# Can I escape (suppress) C preprocessor macro expansion

Tags: c++, preprocessor

I used the following code:

```
auto t = numeric_limits<decltype(m)>::max() - 1;
```

Later, I needed to `#include <Windows.h>` which has `#define max(a, b)` directive, so I can not use `::max()` method. **Is there a way to suppress macro expansion when calling `::max()` without using `#undef max`?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Define `NOMINMAX` in compiler options or before you include windows.h:

```
#define NOMINMAX
#include <windows.h>
```